# how to find specific strings, using the python regular expression

Tags: python, html, regex

I have this HTML:

```
<li class="news_list_bo"><a href="/news_view.php?article_id=2752">URLHunter 프로그램 버퍼오버플로우 취약점 발견!</a>
<ul class="new_liview">
    <li class="img"><a href="/news_view.php?article_id=2752"><img height="45" width="65" src="/image_article/458226972502b655fa1b7b.jpg" /></a></li>                         
    <li class="text"><a href="/news_view.php?article_id=2752">웹페이지를 구성하는 그림파일, 플래쉬파일, 미디어파일들과 같은 구성요소를 사용자에게 보여주는 URLHunter 프로그램에서 버퍼오...</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the text in the `a` tags like this:

```
>>> tmp_title = re.findall(r'<a href="/news_view.php?article_id=[0-9]+">(.*?)</a>',tmp_str,re.I|re.DOTALL)'
```

However, it doesn't find anything:

```
>>> print tmp_title
[]
```

How can I find the text between `<li class="text"><a href="/news_view.php?article_id=2752">` and `</a></li>`?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using an HTML parser like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to handle most of this rather than trying to wrangle regular expressions into doing all of it. Regular expressions may be good for matching the URLs once the HTML is parsed, though.

We can start by constructing a regular expression to match the URLs you want. Your problem was that `?` has a special meaning in regular expressions. If you need to literally match a `?`, you'll need to escape it. Anyway, here's a regular expression for matching the URLs you want:

```
^/news_view\.php\?article_id=[0-9]+$
```

When you need to find the strings, you can first parse the HTML into a soup:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

See [the documentation's section on `SoupStrainers`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) to improve performance.

Then you can match all `a` tags with a `href` you're interested in:

```
links = soup.find_all('a', href=NEWS_URL_RE)
```

Then you can get all of the text out of the links:

```
link_texts = [link.get_text() for link in links]
```

Comment: you could use `re.escape()` to avoid manually escaping the static part of the regex.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes, but then there are parts that have to be not escaped, and this is a one-time deal since we're not generating text to convert into regular expressions.

Comment: I've not said that you *must* use it. It might be easier to read/debug if a reader of your code is not forced to check whether the escaping is correct and it is easier to replace the string if the need arise.

Comment: that is not what i mean, i wanna find some string between a href="/news_view.php?article_id=[0-9]+"> and </a>, not some url.

Comment: @user1610707: This doesn't find URLs. It finds text contained in links to particular URLs.